# Oracle APEX Maximize Region Button

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to achieve a customized maximize option for Oracle APEX maximize region button. Currently, the maximize button just maximizes and covers the entire page.
I would rather want the maximize button to maximize the region but still have the top navigation bar visible.
So basically I need a way to control the height of the maximized region in some way so that I can still make the top nav bar visible when it is maximized.

Here is the CSS code snippet for the is-maximized class:

```
.js-showMaximizeButton.is-maximized {
    z-index: 500;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

When I try to adjust the 'top' property of this class, it just increases the width of the top bar of the maximized window but does not show the nav bar beneath it.

Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: It looks like you did not complete your sentence explaining what happens with your current code

Comment: sorry, it was cut off somehow, I have put the text back.